# How do I switch to another XIB and complete release the previous XIB?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

I am currently in a project creating an iPad book. Unfortunately, since this is my first iPad project I am coding in a very unconventional style.

This is a 20 page book and I have 20 XIBs. On each XIB I am calling the next XIB, but my fear is that the current XIB isn't getting unloaded and still is taking up memory. When I am about on page 10 or so, the app will crash due to `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

I am switching views using 2 different methods (I don't know which one will better suit my purpose):

```
#METHOD 1
-(IBAction)NextPage:(id)sender
{
    nextPage = [[NextPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextPage" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:nextPage.view];
    [self presentModalViewController:nextPage animated:YES];
    [self.view release]; // this was added to hopefully release the current view. 
}


#METHOD 2
-(IBAction)NextPage:(id)sender
{
    NextPage *nextpage = [[[NextPage alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:nextpage animated:YES];
}
```

Each view has buttons and stuff, but I want to make sure I complete erase them from memory on each page call.

I used `dealloc` to try to remove the view, but when I check for memory leaks and go back and forth between pages, the memory crawls up.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [view release]; // don't know which is which 
    [self.view release]; // is this correct?
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just switching between pages in a book, you probably shouldn't be presenting modally.  Instead, you could just swap out views.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html

> ... transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion: methods to
>   swap out entire sets of views for new ones.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:

Another option would be to use layers within a view.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/introduction-to-calayers-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If you present the next page modally (as you are doing), the current page won't be released.  Instead, set your window's `rootViewController` to the new page.

Comment: and how would I exactly do this?

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController could handle this much more simply. Take a look at the documentation. Also, as of iOS5 there is now a book type viewController that may serve you well.